# Use Rake task to add new named route into routes file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-routing, rake-task

I'm writing a rake task to copy over some files to my app. The last part also needs to update my app's routes file with some new routes. Is there a way to do this within the rake task similar to `route` in `Rails::Generators` ?

I want to be able to do write something like this to my route file.

```
namespace :foo do
  namespace :bar do
    get 'test'
  end
end
```

All this without having to do a use `File` methods

Answer (score 0):

If the change is temporary to that request, just call draw on your application routes again.

```
YourAppName::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :foo do
    namespace :bar do
      get 'test'
    end
  end
end
```

If the change is going to be permanent, wrap this code in a class and call it in your routes.rb inside the draw block, as explained [here](http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are so concerned with whether or not you can, that you have overlooked whether or not you should.  You can with the File class in ruby(http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/File.html).  I wouldn't though if it were me.  I would just update it so that VCS knows about the changes.  There are just too many things that could go wrong for me to risk it.  That is just my opinion though.